# Eclipse - How to contribute action to "New" section in "File" menu?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, swt, rcp

I develop Eclipse IDE based RCP application. I want to contribute action, for ex. "New Custom Project", and I want that action to be displayed in following way: 
`File > New > New Custom Project`. To be specific, I like to add my custom action somewhere like on that picture:

[image]

I know  how to add action to File menu, but I don't have any idea how to place it "deeper", in "New" section.

Is there any way to obtain such thing? What *locationURI* should I use to place my action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point to contribute a 'File > New' wizard.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards"> 
  <category 
    id="com.xyz.XYZ.Web" 
    name="Web Wizards" 
  </category> 
  <wizard 
      id="com.xyz.wizard1" 
      name="XYZ artifact" 
      category="com.xyz.XYZ.Web" 
      icon="./icons/XYZwizard1.png"
      class="com.xyz.XYZWizard1"> 
      <description> 
          Create a simple XYZ artifact and set initial content 
      </description> 
       <selection class="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/>          
  </wizard> 
 </extension>
```

Once you have defined a new wizard you can add it to the 'shortcuts' list you show for a specific perspective using the `newWizardShortcut` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions"> 
    <perspectiveExtension 
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective"> 
        <newWizardShortcut id="com.xyz.wizard1"/> 
    </perspectiveExtension> 
</extension>
```

Note that you might have to reset or customize the perspective to get the new definitions picked up.

Comment: I have been using Wizards for long time, but I don't know about perspectiveExtension, and it works well. many thanks. PS: resetting perspective is not needed, but it should be run as an Eclipse Product, instead of plugin